# python import from different directory doesnt work

Tags: python, import, modulenotfounderror, relative-import

Quite new to python (using v3.11).  I am trying to `import` something from another directory.  I tried several different ways and the only way i was able to make it work is by adding ABSOLUTE path using `sys.path.insert`, which is obviously not correct. I suspect it is because im attempting to test class with factory method and I feel like i missed something.

This is what i have:

```
└── /project
    ├── /src
    │   ├── /services
    │   │   └── service1.py
    │   │         class DataService:
    │   │             def write_data(self,data,location):
    │   └── containers.py
    │             from dependency_injector import containers, providers
    │             from services.service1 import DataService
    │             class Container(containers.DeclarativeContainer):
    │                 data_service = providers.Factory(DataService)
    └── /tests
        └── /services-tests
            └── test_service1.py
                     import pytest
                     from containers import Container #<--- ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'containers'
                     data_service = Container.data_service()
```

As you can see in `tests\services-tests\test_service1.py`, i am attempting to `import`, and it fails.  As I said, I tried several things, but the only way I got it to work is by adding ABSOLUTE path using `sys.path.insert`, which is obviously not correct way.  Any ideas where I may have gone wrong?

Comment: I don't see any `__init__.py` files in there - those are needed for python to recognise directories are packages. Never use `sys.path` hacks in this case

Answer (score 0):

Does `python3 -m tests.services-tests.test_service1` work for you when you are in project folder?

Answer (score 0):

This is a scoping issue. While both are under `Project`, `test_service1.py` is in the folder `project/tests` and `containers.py` is 'out of scope' for it to be simply imported without identifying that it is in a parallel folder `project/src`.

So, `from containers import Container` would only work if both Python scripts were in the same folder. You are almost at the final answer when you added the absolute path using `sys.path.insert`. In many workflows where developers deal with huge repositories of code, they often do this (and this is recommended):

```
sys.path.append("path/to/src")
from containers import Container
```

There are dot imports available where a single dot represents the current directory, double dot represent a parent directory, three dots represent grandparent directories and so on. So a rough workaround is

```
from ...src import containers.Container
```

This is always 50-50 for me and I prefer the `sys.path.append()` method everytime. The most I've used is 2 dots so 3 dots is something to try.

Additionally, good practice requires an `__init__.py` file in the directory to tell python that it is a package and relative imports can be done.

Answer (score 0):

You should add an (empty) `__init__.py` file in all subdirectories of `project`. This makes `src` and `tests` into packages. The imports should read

```
from src.services.service1 import DataService # or
from .service1 import DataService # relative import
```

and

```
from src.containers import Container
```

and so on. Both the tests and main script should be run from the `project` dir using the `-m` switch.